# Does Spring Adds HSTS header for every response?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Hie, I was going through various spring-security modules. and I was keen about HSTS (HTTP strict transport security) and at the same time performance.

Does spring Adds HSTS headers for every request it hits or it only for the first time?

is there the way to optimize it? I know optimizing security is a crazy idea but out of Curiosity, I am asking this.

Even I have gone through [spring-security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.x/reference/html/web-app-security.html#headers-hsts) docs. but docs don't say any information about this.

I strongly feel that there is no need for spring to send HSTS header for every response.

Answer (score 1):

By default the HSTS header is added to secure requests. You can customize this behaviour by setting a custom `RequestMatcher`. Then the header will only be sent back if the request matches your customization.
For example:

```
http
    .headers()
        .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
            .requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"));
```

You can read more in the [HSTS header configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/HeadersConfigurer.HstsConfig.html) section of the documentation.

Comment: @Eletheria Does this increase the performance or It acts in a reverse way? making performance much worse

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram It depends on what your matcher is. If it's broader than the default, then the header will be added for more requests, and more lines of code will be executed. If it's narrower then it will be added for fewer requests. Performance also depends on how the browser handles the HSTS header. I haven't run performance tests to verify this but overall, I don't think you would see a significant performance impact.